# Is there a Maven plugin to fetch an rpm

Tags: java, linux, maven, rpm, apt

As part of my current procedure, I have to do a Linux package fetch, followed by a Maven build.

Is there a Maven plugin to fetch a Linux package ( `rpm -i xxx` or `apt-get install xxx` )?

maven-exec-plugin enables this. but is there a more specialized plugin that wraps data on top?

Note : - maven-rpm-plugin and maven-apt-plugin seem to allow you to create rpm packages, not to fetch them

Comment: The question is why you need a rpm installation before a particular maven buil?

Comment: I am integrating C and Java code into the same project using maven-make-plugin for the C portion. The C portion has dependencies resolved using apt-get or rpm. Traditionally, the installation of dependent rpms is left outside Makefiles ?

Comment: You can do the step of installation of the rpm inside a job of a ci solution like Jenkins/Hudson etc.

Comment: I've not come across a specialized plugin. I think it is generally a good idea to reduce the number of manual installation steps, so I can follow your thought train, here. Perhaps you can use the Antrun plugin and ask the user to confirm before you make changes that affect their larger system or put it in a profile. Do you really need applications (`xxx`) installed, or do you really only need some artifacts to rewrap those into your application?

Comment: @Ranjan did you ever find such a maven plugin?  I'm looking for something that at least checks whether an RPM has been installed.  Similar to you, I need it when doing a Maven build of some native code on which Java code depends.

Comment: @Ranjan here's my question similar http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23476684/maven-plugin-which-checks-that-rpm-has-been-installed