# maven plugin, ant task, or gradle plugin which checks that rpm has been installed

Tags: maven, ant, openssl, gradle, rpm

Is anyone aware of a maven plugin, ant task, or gradle plugin which can verify that an rpm has already been installed on a Linux system?  All the plugins coming up in google results seem to be focused on creating RPMs rather than checking for RPM dependencies e.g.

- c-builds plugin http://mojo.codehaus.org/cbuild-parent/
- rpm-maven-plugin http://mojo.codehaus.org/rpm-maven-plugin/index.html

Context: we have some maven-native-plugin artifacts which depend on the /usr/include/openssl/ssl.h and /usr/lib/libssl.a from the openssl-devel RPM.  I'd like a way to verify that the openssl-devel RPM has been installed.

My question is kind of similar to [Is there a Maven plugin to fetch an rpm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18554908/is-there-a-maven-plugin-to-fetch-an-rpm).  But I'm okay if the plugin just confirms that an RPM is installed on a Red Hat Linux system, actually fetching the RPM would just be a nice to have.

Comment: This question appears to belong on another site in the Stack Exchange network because its not about programming. Perhaps [Super User](https://www.superuser.com/) or [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/) would have recommendations for package manager plug-ins.

Comment: @jww Thanks for the tip that Super User and Server Fault may have a membership which has dealt with this situation.  I'd disagree that this question "[is] not about programming".  I'm writing C/C++ software that compiles and links to a third party library (openssl).  Part of programming is figuring out how to automate builds using tools like Maven.  I'm trying to learn if others have figured out a way to tell maven to verify that a dependency from an RPM (libssl.a) is available so that other programmers on the team get a good error if libssl.a isn't installed on their machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write a small maven enforcer rule that just calls Runtime.getRuntime().exec("rpm -q openssl-devel") and parse the output. It's simple and fast. If you don't find the rpm the enforcer can break the build and give you a heads up.

- http://maven.apache.org/enforcer/maven-enforcer-plugin/
- http://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-api/writing-a-custom-rule.html